# Trigger with If loop shows compilation error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-trigger

I have created a trigger which will insert data into table in different database. if the salary is higher than 10000. But it shows compilation error.

```
    create or replace Trigger insert_ti
after insert on emp1
for each row
begin
IF :new.salary = 10000 THEN
{
    insert into emp@db2todb1 
    values(:new.emp_id, :new.last_name, :new.first_name, :new.email, :new.hire_date, :new.salary, :new.manager_id);
}
END IF;
end;
/
```

It shows Trigger created with compilation error

Comment: Check `select * from user_errors` or simply `show errors` to know what's the actual error. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56661515/edit) your question and paste that information. By the way, curly braces `{}` aren't valid in PL/SQL, which is an obvious error.

Comment: @KaushikNayak I did it thankk you sooo mucchh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's Oracle 11g, please remove the curly braces and compile it.

Also, it's a good practice to provide column names in the target table while inserting the records. Blind insert would cause issues if a new column in added to the same table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER insert_ti AFTER
    INSERT ON emp1
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :new.salary > 10000 THEN
        INSERT INTO emp@db2todb1 VALUES (
            :new.emp_id
            , :new.last_name
            , :new.first_name
            , :new.email
            , :new.hire_date
            , :new.salary
            , :new.manager_id
        );
    END IF;
END;
```